# Understanding EXPLAIN ANALYZE query plan

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I have the following output

```
Merge Join (cost=31843.55..32194.92 rows=30215 width=36)
           (actual time=496.720..510.071 rows=38381 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (movies.year = people.birth_year)
  -> Sort (cost=9905.45..9918.62 rows=5268 width=22)
     (actual time=151.781..152.690 rows=5634 loops=1) // <---- !!!! LOOKING HERE !!!!
       Sort Key: movies.year
       Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 729kB
     -> Seq Scan on movies (cost=0.00..9579.81 rows=5268 width=22)
        (actual time=145.826..149.340 rows=7640 loops=1) // <---- !!!! LOOKING HERE !!!!
          Filter: (title > ’y’::text)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 456425 // <---- !!!! LOOKING HERE !!!!
  -> Sort (cost=21936.87..21953.89 rows=6808 width=18)
     (actual time=344.918..347.980 rows=38465 loops=1)
       Sort Key: people.birth_year
       Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 423kB
     -> Seq Scan on people (cost=0.00..21503.44 rows=6808 width=18)
        (actual time=341.883..343.847 rows=4151 loops=1)
          Filter: (name > ’zeke’::text)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 1099324
Planning time: 0.450 ms
Execution time: 511.988 ms
```

I care to know the selectivity estimate for `title > 'y'`.
This plan says `Rows Removed by Filter: 456425`.

**The total rows that we have is** `464065`.

Since `456425` rows were removed by the filter, we selected 
`464065 - 456425 = 7640` rows which is mentioned in the `Seq Scan` line.

But how come the topmost `Sort` shows actual rows numbers as `5634`? Where is it coming from?

I thought it might be related to the second sort operation, but those are completely different branches.

Is there any way to know if tables fit in memory or not? Plan indicate how much memory is being used, but I do not see them indicating whether all this fits in memory or not.

Comment: You should preserve the indention of the execution plan as that is important to understand it as well - the indention shows the nesting level of the different plan nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain, but my guess is that the “Merge Join” consumed only 5634 rows from the “Sort” node.

PostgreSQL execution works “on demand”, that is, a result row is requested from a lower node whenever the upper node needs it.

And while the “Sort” definitely needs all rows from the “Seq Scan”, the merge join could be finished before all available sorted rows have been read.

That was not your question, but to speed up the query, you need indexes on `people (name)` and `movies (title)`.

To know if your data are cached, use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. Then you see the number of blocks that were found in the cache (hit) and the number of blocks read from the operating system (read). Note, however, that "read" data might come from the file system cache.